# Why the Graphics Card on my MacBook Pro is always on "High perf." status?

Tags: mac, power, gpu, power-management

After I've installed Nvidia Cuda Drivers the Activity Monitor show that Graphics Card is always on High Perf. status. No application that "Requires High Perf GPU" is running and the battery goes down quickly, very quickly.

Any idea how to solve that expensive problem?

Comment: Somewhat related. I have the same thing happening to me!  Same Cuda driver installed, but I’ve had Cuda on it for about a year. It started like 3 or 4 months ago - it’s always running on the 750M. This is where it gets interesting: I sent my laptop in to get the screen replaced due to a reflective coating issue. When they were replacing it (I also told them I had been having the locked graphics card problem), they called me and said that there was a possible issue and that they could replace the motherboard for $600. My laptop works, so I didn’t do it, but I’m curious why they suggested it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using an external monitor? MacBook start using discrete card if external screen is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Remove the unsupported drivers you installed until such time as nVidia fixes them.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The high performance setting forces the computer to use the discrete card. My guess is that with the nvidia drivers installed from nvidia that it sets this to ensure the nvidia card is being used and not the integrated gpu.

Comment: I don't have any nvidia drivers, just a vanilla High Sierra install and mine won't come off of High Perf.